# Flink Scala Job Runtime Error : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink, amazon-emr

I am trying to run a simple flink streaming job on AWS EMR. The purpose is very simple for now:

1. Consume data from Kafka in flink
2. Load to another topic in kafka.

I am using the following dependencies:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
val flinkVersion = "1.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-scala" % flinkVersion,
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala" % flinkVersion,
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-kafka" % flinkVersion
)
```

Flink code that i am using is :

```
private val serdeSchema = new SimpleStringSchema

val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    val stream = env
     .addSource(createKafkaConsumer(kafkaInputTopic
       , kafkaBrokers, kafkaConfig("consumerGroupId").toString
       , kafkaConfig("defaultReset").toString))
  
    stream
     .map((s: String) => s)
     .addSink(createKafkaProducer(kafkaOutputTopic, kafkaBrokers))
  
    env.execute(jobConfig("jobName").toString)
    
  }
  
  def createKafkaProducer(kafkaTopic: String, kafkaBrokers: String): FlinkKafkaProducer[String] = {
    
    val producer = new FlinkKafkaProducer[String](kafkaBrokers,
      kafkaTopic, serdeSchema)
    producer
  }
  
  def createKafkaConsumer(kafkaInputTopic: String
                          , kafkaBrokers: String
                          , consumerGroup:String
                          , defaultReset: String): FlinkKafkaConsumer[String] = {
  
    val properties = new Properties()
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", kafkaBrokers)
    properties.setProperty("group.id", consumerGroup)
    properties.setProperty("enable.auto.commit" , "false")
    properties.setProperty("auto.offset.reset" , defaultReset)
    
    val consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer[String](kafkaInputTopic, serdeSchema, properties)
    consumer
  }
```

I generate a assembly jar using sbt. I use the following command to run the job on EMR

```
/bin/flink run -c com.example.FlinkConsumer flink/target/scala-2.11/flink-assembly-0.1.jar
```

Below is the stack trace

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Job failed (JobID: c458520153e875811c46c386b9ec605e)
    at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.lambda$null$6(ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.java:112)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:616)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:591)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1975)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.lambda$pollResourceAsync$21(RestClusterClient.java:565)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:750)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1975)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$8(FutureUtils.java:291)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:750)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postFire(CompletableFuture.java:575)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:943)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:147)
    at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.lambda$null$6(ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.java:110)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:110)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:192)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.maybeHandleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:186)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.updateTaskExecutionStateInternal(DefaultScheduler.java:180)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:484)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:380)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:279)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:194)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:74)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:152)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:170)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:225)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SerializationSchema.open(Lorg/apache/flink/api/common/serialization/SerializationSchema$InitializationContext;)V
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.KafkaSerializationSchemaWrapper.open(KafkaSerializationSchemaWrapper.java:61)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.open(FlinkKafkaProducer.java:808)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.openFunction(FunctionUtils.java:36)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.open(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:102)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSink.open(StreamSink.java:48)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeStateAndOpen(StreamTask.java:1007)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.lambda$beforeInvoke$0(StreamTask.java:454)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$SynchronizedStreamTaskActionExecutor.runThrowing(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:94)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.beforeInvoke(StreamTask.java:449)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:461)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:707)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:532)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

It looks like a version issue, but i tried with various versions, i don't see this open method, but i think in the serialize it calls the open method and unable to find one. Can someone please help . I am new to flink.

Comment: I don't know sbt, but if you're using EMR's Flink support, then most Flink libraries should be flagged as "provided" (to use Maven terminology) so that they're not in your jar, as they're on the classpath from the Flink installation that EMR is providing.

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding provided, but now getting class not found exception: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer

Comment: It worked finally. Thanks. It was the below dependencies: ` "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-scala" % flinkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala" % flinkVersion,
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-kafka" % flinkVersion`

Comment: I'll post my comment as an answer, so it's more visible to other SO users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using EMR's Flink support, then most Flink libraries should be flagged as "provided" so that they're not in your jar, as they're on the classpath from the Flink installation that EMR is providing. You'll still need to explicitly include anything that's not provided by EMR (e.g. `flink-connector-kafka`).